# Primefaces DataTable Overlap

Tags: java, jsf, web, primefaces

[image]

Any idea guys how to solve these? Im just making a UI so my codes are not connecting to the database yet or objects since we just need to display. I need to wrap the description text.

Comment: Your question is unclear. At a first glance it seems that you are suffering a display bug, but from your question it seems that you have another problem. Be more detailed

Comment: What is overlapping exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebug for Firefox or Developers Toolbar for IE to locate the ID/Name/Class for the datatable header and footer and in the file change the width of the datatable as required/ by % or by px. You may want to use the !important tag with each style amendment, to ensure the style is implemented.